# Rename a file with find without knowing the directory

Tags: linux, find

I need to find a file, lets say `passfail.txt` in a subdirectory of `X` which contains random generated directories `(X/randomDir/passfail.txt)`.
I want to rename that file to `passfail_SOMESTRING.txt` while keeping it in this unknown directory. I tried a few methods to crop the filename for the `mv` in the `-exec` part of `find`, such as `dirname`, but none seem to work... Any idea how I could do that?

Comment: If your `find` has the `-execdir` option that seems like the easiest way to go.

Answer (score 1):

```
    ~$ find . -type f -name "Avan*mp4" -exec rename 's/Avant.*mp4/new.mp4/' {} \; -print
    ./tmp/Avantaccident.mp4
    ~$ ls -lrth tmp/*mp4
    -rw-r--r-- 1 francois francois 4.9M Feb 10 19:43 tmp/new.mp4
    ~$
```

using rename should work also with a huge list of subdirectories